# How to show only the deepest taxonomy term in a drupal view, having used hierarchical select to tag content

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a site for sporting products. 
I use hierarchical select to tag the products that are added to the site - and the term lineage is saved, so Taxonomy menu automatically creates nice hierarchical menus linking to the taxonomy pages - which I've overridden using views.

See here for an example:  http://dayalssports.com/product-menu/badminton/rackets

The rackets are grouped according to taxonomy term. 
Problem is, as the term lineage is saved, the taxonomy view displays all the terms, in a seemingly random order. It doesn't display them parent->Child1->Child2 etc as you would expect.

I want to display only the deepest term. So instead of having:

***Rackets , Y Series Rackets , Badminton***

which is out of order anyway, I just get

***Y Series Rackets***

Is there a way to do this? Or is there at least a way to order them correctly?

The correct order should be ***Rackets , Badminton , Y Series Rackets***